# Por que minha média aritmética está errada?

Tags: javascript

```
var n1 = prompt("Nota 1: ");
alert(n1);
var n2 = prompt("Nota 2: ");
alert(n2);
var media = (n1+n2)/2;


if(media >= 6){
    alert("Aprovado!\n\nMédia: " + media);
}else{
    alert("Reprovado!\n\nMédia: " + media);
}
```

Quando faço por console.log o resultado aparece correto, mas por prompt não.

Comment: `console.log` no lugar de `prompt`? Como seria isso? Aliás, o retorno de `prompt` sempre é uma *string*. Pense sobre isso.

Answer (score 2):

Porque o prompt retorna `string`. No caso `n1+n2` você está concatenando strings e não somando números.

O correto seria converter os valores do prompt em tipo número:

```js
var n1 = Number(prompt("Nota 1: "));
alert(n1);
var n2 = Number(prompt("Nota 2: "));
alert(n2);
var media = (n1+n2)/2;


if(media >= 6){
    alert("Aprovado!\n\nMédia: " + media);
}else{
    alert("Reprovado!\n\nMédia: " + media);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Isso acontece pois o `window.prompt` retorna o valor em `string`. Diferente do `PHP`, o `javascript` não vai somar o valor utilizando apenas o sinal `+`. Nesse caso, o `javascript` vai apenas concatenar os valores em string e depois dividir por 2.

Exemplo:

Quando você informa o valor de 10 para `n1` e `n2`, com o sinal de `+` você estará informando para o `javascript` concatenado esses valores, ou seja, `10` concatenado com `10` é igual a `1010`, dividido por 2, 505.

Para solucionar esse problema, você deve converter de `string` para `integer`. Para essa conversão você pode utilizar o **[parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)** ou **[parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)**

```js
var n1 = parseInt(prompt("Nota 1: "));
alert(n1);
var n2 = parseInt(prompt("Nota 2: "));
alert(n2);

var media = (n1+n2)/2;

if(media >= 6){
    alert("Aprovado!\n\nMédia: " + media);
}else{
    alert("Reprovado!\n\nMédia: " + media);
}
```